# How to formulate a statement in r?

Tags: r

So this is my question: I have been given a data set and the instruction are:

> Growth patterns are generated by transforming the X variable into a new categorical variable, which can be named "growth". First category is assigned to islands in the X variable that are between 15 to 50.

So that is the question, but my main headache is how to write the "between 15 to 50 in R language. This is what I have

```
growth$mediumgrowth.islands <- growth$SasiaUrban.X[growth$SasiaUrban.X ???]
```

But I do not know what command to put in the ??? part.

Comment: Your question is not clear (and you should make the title specific to your question), but it sounds like you are looking for the cut function, which turns a continuous variable into a binned categorical variable. (However, your question doesn't specify what the second, third etc categories are...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get something reproducible:

```
set.seed(47)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(60, 100, replace = TRUE))
```

Your exact questions, how to write "between 15 and 50" is answered by telling R "greater than 15 *and* less than 50":

```
## What's between 15 and 50?
df$x > 15 & df$x <= 50
```

That gives you a vector of TRUE/FALSE. It's the same length as `x` and is TRUE when your criteria match (between 15 and 50), and FALSE otherwise. (NB: I used greater than 15 and less than or equal to 50, you might want to adjust that.) Filling your "???" would be `growth$SasiaUrban.X[growth$SasiaUrban.X > 15 & growth$SasiaUrban.X <= 50]`.

```
## We could assign this as a new column
df$between15and50 <- df$x > 15 & df$x <= 50
```

If you want more categories, it makes sense to do them all at once, and `cut` makes this easy:

```
## Or we could use cut
cut(df$x, breaks = c(0, 15, 50, 100))

df$category <- cut(df$x, breaks = c(0, 15, 50, 100))

## Adding labels instead
df$category2 <- cut(df$x, breaks = c(0, 15, 50, 100),
    labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))

head(df)
```